# Is there a word that combines aerial, aquatic, and terrestrial?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that something suitable to both land and water is called amphibious but I am looking for a word that describes something that is suitable to land, air, and water. I don't believe such an animal exists but I am still curious as to whether there is a word for it.

Comment: Some seabirds might be regarded as having this quality - they fly, can walk and can dive/swim.  See [gannets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gannet) and [cormorants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cormorant).

Comment: Also the [loon](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Common_Loon/lifehistory) -- not very agile on land, but an expert diver and a good flyer.

Comment: I believe that the best-known animals that inhabit the land, sea, or air are the various species of dragon, but I think not all biomes at once for any one species.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

See **triphibian**, defined by [American heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=triphibian) as

> Designed to operate on land, on water, or in air.

Comment: Note that in "amphibious", the first part comes from the greek "amphí", meaning "on both sides", whereas "triphi" does not have a greek provenance, and is an "artificial" word, made up by replacing "am" with "tri".

Comment: I never realised that [Action Man](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Land-Sea-Air-Action-Man/dp/1872727999) was triphibian!

Comment: I get the feeling Triathlon and Triathlete are related to this prefix wise, though you have to replace Air with Cycling, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @AlexStragies Sure, but *tribious* sounds like it would have to do with a particularly difficult-to-dislodge invasive species found on starships...

Comment: @Ryan: I guess you could say that, but not because they have to do with air, land and water. The Greek-originated prefix "tri-" simply stands for "three". Triathlon is called so because this sport consists of three distinct disciplines (cf. biathlon, pentathlon, decathlon). The word "triphibian" may be meant to describe *specific* environments something or someone can operate in but its "tri-" prefix still stands for just "three".

Comment: Great question and great answer too. Last night I was wondering whether multimedia or SUV would fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

If a new word is needed, why not ***panbious***?

Exchanging the greek

***amphi*** - meaning ['*both; on two sides*'](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/amphi)

for the greek

***pan*** - meaning ['*all; of everything*'](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/pan-).

Answer (score 0):

triphibious is okay but triphibious can also applies to 3 types of terrestrial. so the best word is AEROAMPHIBIOUS.

Comment: Does that appear in a any dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

So wouldn't ollaphibios be a better word olla means all. So the word "all" in my head would refer to all of our main categories of the earth's makeup land, water, sky. Not sure if that would be the correct spelling I just looked up the Greek translation for "all".

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary reference or two.

Comment: The poster is not looking for a word that can be coined for the occasion, they are curious as to if "there **is** a word "

Answer (score -1):

Omniphibios would be better, I think. Or spanphibios could work.
Omni - all; of all things; in all ways or places.
Span - the full extent of something from end to end.

Why not invent a word for your purposes? That's what Shakespeare did.

Comment: This would be improved with an authoritative definition and reference for the given word.